# Значения по умолчанию в функциях Си

Tags: c

Возможно ли применять значения по умолчанию для аргументов функций Си или эта возможность есть только в Си++?

Comment: Сейчас проверил в справочнике Шилдта по C, там о таком и речи нет, видно это фича плюсов.

Comment: @avp: на этапе компиляции конечно же. наличие или отсутсвия рантайма тут не причем

Comment: @renegator: именно архитектурное решение об отсутствии рантайма определяет невозможность введения в язык параметров по умолчанию. Не забывайте о возможности динамического вызова из shared library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нельзя. все

Comment: Коротко и ясно)))

Comment: На слово верить, это не по технарски)

Comment: По крайней мере, когда я 25 лет назад в университете учил Си, ничего такого не было.

Comment: Вы статьи научные писали когда нибудь?

Comment: Диплом руководитель обещал опубликовать, но скорее всего соврал

Comment: Ок, возьмем диплом если ближе, в обязательно порядке при при констатации какого либо факта если он не доказывается в вашей работе должна быть ссылка, на литературу, все это конечно халевар, но "нельзя, все" это не ответ, это что-то помню 25 лет назад, а уже давно есть стандарт С99

Comment: Есть в математике такая школа интуиционизм (школа Брауэра). Там много интересного, и, кроме всего прочего, интуиционисты критикуют всю классическую математику и не признают ее доказательства за истинные. Если вопрошающий считает что "нельзя" является с его точки зрения достаточным ответом, то в его системе аксиом так оно и есть

Comment: Мне ваша точка зрения нравится))) с девушками удобнее) но вы сейчас для себя или для кого отвечаете? тут понятно что парень спрашивал уча язык, а если ответ не правельный?
К сожалению дальше не могу откоментрровать, но я уже ответил и так что передать нельзя по умолчанию значения, читайте ниже!

Comment: @gympi, посмотрите код, который делает компилятор C. Каким образом можно передать, что вызывающая сторона не задала фактический параметр ?  

Дело, собственно, в различной философии C и C++. В плюсах существует run-time среда времени исполнения, а в С принципиально нет **языковой run-time** среды (только библиотеки (а это **не часть языка**, написанные ,вообще говоря, не обязательно на C).

Comment: Да все правильно. В С++ есть. Си нет. Не на слово верить, а развеять сомнения)

Comment: Судя по тому, что decodder принял ответ, ему он оказался полезен. значит не только для себя. Касаемо обоснования каких-либо суждений, то тут тоже дискутируемо - хватит ли моего авторитета или нужен еще авторитет Шилдта, Риччи и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще то дело не в коде, как тут один товарищ говорил выше. Это фича делается на этапе компиляции. Вообще иногда полезна чтобы с макросами не мудрить. Но можно прекрасно жить и без нее как впрочем и без всего что есть в C++ и нету в современном С.

Answer (score 1):

Только что проверил, во всех компиляторах, что есть у меня (gcc, pcc, tcc, dmc, occ, bcc) -все выдают ошибку.

Единственный компилятор, что не не дал ошибку и скомпилировал программу с аргументами в объявлении функции по умолчанию - это LC (он же LCC).
Программа отработала верно при этом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum (int a1, int b1) {

    return (a1 + b1);
}

int mult (int a2, int b2) {

    return (a2 * b2);
}

int all(int a=2, int b=3) { // значения по умолчанию

    return (mult((sum(a,a)), (sum(b,b))));

}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{


printf ("summa %d", all()); // вызываем функцию all с пустым списком аргументов

return 0;
}
```